# How to create 3D NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray

How can I create a 3D Mutable Array of Int?

I want to be able to insert an element by saying `arr[4][3][5] = 4`, and not have to determine the size of the array beforehand.

Comment: please show us some code you have done to solve your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Discussion (see below for final code)

Here is a way to do it: First we extend `_ArrayType` with a subscript that automatically extends the array when accessing an index out of bounds. We will the array with a given `fallback` value:

```
extension _ArrayType {
    subscript (extending pos: Int, fallback fallback: Generator.Element) -> Generator.Element {
        mutating get {
            while count <= pos { append(fallback) }
            return self[pos]
        }
        mutating set {
            while count <= pos { append(fallback) }
            self[pos] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

This is useable like this:

```
var a : [Int] = []
a[extending: 3, fallback: 0] = 10
print(a) // [0, 0, 0, 10]
```

Now we can extend the 3-dimensional arrays to have a convenient subscript that auto-extends like this:

```
extension _ArrayType where
    Generator.Element : _ArrayType,
    Generator.Element.Generator.Element : _ArrayType {

    typealias T = Generator.Element.Generator.Element.Generator.Element

    subscript (x: Int, y: Int, z: Int, `default`: T) -> T {
        mutating get {
            return self[extending: x, fallback: []][extending: y, fallback: []][extending: z, fallback: `default`]
        }
        mutating set {
            self[extending: x, fallback: []][extending: y, fallback: []][extending: z, fallback: `default`] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var array : [[[Int?]]] = []
array[1, 1, 0, nil] = 10
array[2, 0, 1, nil] = 4
print(array) // [[], [[], [Optional(10)]], [[nil, Optional(4)]]]
```

Now if you want it even more convenient by telling beforehand what the default value should be for a certain type you can create a `HasDefault` protocol:

```
protocol HasDefault {
    static var `default` : Self { get }
}
```

And extend your types with it:

```
extension Int : HasDefault {
    static var `default` = 0
}

extension Bool : HasDefault {
    static var `default` = false
}
```

Also make a subscript that doesn't take the last argument:

```
extension _ArrayType where
    Generator.Element : _ArrayType,
    Generator.Element.Generator.Element : _ArrayType,
    Generator.Element.Generator.Element.Generator.Element : HasDefault {

    typealias E = Generator.Element.Generator.Element.Generator.Element

    subscript (x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) -> E {
        mutating get {
            return self[x, y, z, E.`default`]
        }
        mutating set {
            self[x, y, z, E.`default`] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Now this is useable the way you want it:

```
var array : [[[Int]]] = []
array[0, 1, 0] = 3
array[1, 2, 3] = 10

print(array[2, 0, 1]) // 0
print(array) // [[[], [3]], [[], [], [0, 0, 0, 10]], [[0, 0]]]
```

Unfortunately it's not (yet) possible to extend `Optional` with `HasDefault` (which would be `nil`), but you can make a custom subscript for `NilLiteralConvertible`s which `Optional` conforms to:

```
extension _ArrayType where
    Generator.Element : _ArrayType,
    Generator.Element.Generator.Element : _ArrayType,
    Generator.Element.Generator.Element.Generator.Element : NilLiteralConvertible {

    subscript (x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) -> Generator.Element.Generator.Element.Generator.Element {
        mutating get {
            return self[x, y, z, nil]
        }
        mutating set {
            self[x, y, z, nil] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Use like this:

```
var array : [[[Int?]]] = []
array[0, 1, 0] = 3
array[1, 2, 3] = 10

print(array[2, 0, 1]) // nil
print(array) // [[[], [3]], [[], [], [nil, nil, nil, 10]], [[nil, nil]]]
```

I heavily recommend this approach, since the whole purpose of `Optional`s is to represent no value.

#### TL;DR / The final code

```
extension _ArrayType {
    subscript (extending pos: Int, fallback fallback: Generator.Element) -> Generator.Element {
        mutating get {
            while count <= pos { append(fallback) }
            return self[pos]
        }
        mutating set {
            while count <= pos { append(fallback) }
            self[pos] = newValue
        }
    }
}

extension _ArrayType where
    Generator.Element : _ArrayType,
    Generator.Element.Generator.Element : _ArrayType,
    Generator.Element.Generator.Element.Generator.Element : NilLiteralConvertible {

    subscript (x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) -> Generator.Element.Generator.Element.Generator.Element {
        mutating get {
            return self[extending: x, fallback: []][extending: y, fallback: []][extending: z, fallback: nil]
        }
        mutating set {
            self[extending: x, fallback: []][extending: y, fallback: []][extending: z, fallback: nil] = newValue
        }
    }
}

var array : [[[Int?]]] = []
array[0, 1, 0] = 3
array[1, 2, 3] = 10

print(array[2, 0, 1]) // nil
print(array) // [[[], [3]], [[], [], [nil, nil, nil, 10]], [[nil, nil]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var z = [Int](count:10, repeatedValue: 0)
var y = [[Int]](count:10, repeatedValue: z)
var x = [[[Int]]](count:10, repeatedValue: y)

x[A][B][C] = 4
var val = x[2][1][1]
```

Swift 3 in Xcode 8 beta 2 playground

```
var z = [Int](repeatElement(0, count: 10))
var y = [[Int]](repeatElement(z, count: 10))
var x = [[[Int]]](repeatElement(y, count: 10))
```

Possible answer

```
var z = [0]
var y = [z]
var x = [y]

x[0][0].append(2)

x[0].append([1])

x.append([[3,5],[0]])

print(x)

x[0][0][0] = 2

print(x)

//Output
[[[0, 2], [1]], [[3, 5], [0]]]
[[[2, 2], [1]], [[3, 5], [0]]]
```

Comment: These arrays aren't mutable, though

Comment: @Lypsin Of course they are! Why wouldn't they? Try yourself in a Playground, you'll see.

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase my question. I want to be able to add an element to any index, not just 0-29 or 0-19 or 0-9.

Comment: Do you want the element at the index to be nil until you add something into the array at that index?

Comment: I'm not sure how many elements I will add to the array, so I want it to extend its length automatically, like an NSMutableArray

Comment: @Lypsin does that answer your question